# branch with no common ancesters

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I seem to have managed to create a branch that does not stem from the initial commit.

It seemed to happen when pulling changes from the repo. I have managed to get a point where my working branch has all the necessary commits, but my branch history is confusing.

Can I correct it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git does not require a single root commit. In fact, [git.git](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=summary) itself has several root commits (it contains at least root commits for [git](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=e83c5163316f89bfbde7d9ab23ca2e25604af290)'s, [gitk](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=1db95b00a2d2a001fd91cd860a71c639ea04eb53)'s and [gitweb](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=161332a521fe10c41979bcd493d95e2ac562b7ff)'s history)

Since you have already merged successfully, there is no need to "fix" your history, Git will do the right thing™ during future merges.

Comment: but the commits just didn't happen like that!!

Comment: They must have happened like that, otherwise Git wouldn't display them. You said, "it happened when pulling" – so you could have pulled an unrelated repository? "Unrelated" can also happen, when one side rewrites complete history (eg. `git filter-branch`)